# What are good topics to first cover when encountering probability? What are some good books or websites?

Tags: probability

I take it that combinatorics is something that should be one of the first things learned? Is that correct, also what are some good links and resources I can use to begin to learn probability? I ask this because I don't have access to a textbook as I won't be able to find the textbook that is used till I can get in touch with my professor in the fall (I am taking it in the spring). So I am looking for some good resources to use till then.

Comment: It depends really, in axiomatic probability combinatorics almost has no use at all - rather it's all about measure theory

Comment: Providing a course description for your probability course and information about the intended audience (first year university student, advanced undergraduate student, graduate student) would improve your chances of getting a helpful response.

Comment: Do you want a calculus based version or a non-calculus based version?  For the former I highly recommend Larson's book you can get a used copy for like $2 on amazon, here's a link: https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Probability-Harold-J-Larson/dp/0201512866?ie=UTF8&ref_=asap_bc